# Process Explorer showing RAM use of 99.73%

Tags: windows-7, memory, process-explorer

Is it possible for for Process Explorer to show a RAM use of 99.73%, on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (virtual memory disabled to avoid swap)? I thought that Windows was reserving a few % of RAM for itself.

[image]

Comment: @K7AAY I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Is that an answer to the question?

Comment: "virtual memory disabled to avoid swap"  Yes, it will use all available memory if you disable swap, it will drive you right to the edge of the cliff. What's memory supposed to be good for? If you don't use as much as you can, it's very expensive sand.